# Error creating JSON Unexpected Character Sequence

Tags: json, azure, scripting, azure-rm-template

I've been trying to create a basic json for our testes to throw up a machine a and when required. I got most of it done however I am getting the following errors:

```
Line 158 Unexpected character sequence in member name
Line 167 A member with the name 'Properties' already exists
```

I understand 67 needs to be unique, but everytime I change and remove the { it creates more errors.

And unexpected character is the { on line 157, which I'm guessing should be either a string, maybe?

My template is below.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualMachineName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "offer": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultvalue": "Windows",
      "allowedValues": [
        "windows",
        "centos",
        "RHEL"
      ]
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultvalue": "2012-r2-datacenter",
      "allowedValues": [
        "2012-R2-Datacenter",
        "2012-R2",
        "68",
        "72",
        "73",
        "74"
      ]
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultvalue": "standard_A0",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_A0",
        "Standard_A1",
        "standard_A2"
      ]
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ipaddress": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "networkInterfaceName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ContainerName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "autoShutdownStatus": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "autoShutdownTime": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "autoShutdownTimeZone": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "autoShutdownNotificationStatus": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "vnetId": "[resourceId('avset','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
    "stdvhdcontainername": "[concat(parameters('Containername'))]",
    "vmosidiskname": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'-osdisk')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "diagnosticsProfile": {
          "bootDiagnostics": {
            "enabled": true,
            "storageUri": "[concat (parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName')), ['blob']]"
          }
        },
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "offer": "[concat(parameters('offer'))]",
            "sku": "[concat(parameters('offer'))]",
            "version": "latest"
          }
        },
        "osDisk": {
          "vhd": {
            "name": "[variables('vmosidiskname')]",
            "uri": "[concat('http://', parameters('storageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/', variables('stdvhdcontainername'),'/', variables('vmosidiskname'), '.vhd')]"
          },
          "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]"
        },
        "name": "[concat('shutdown-computevm-', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
        "type": "Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules",
        "apiVersion": "2017-04-26-preview",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
          "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownStatus')]",
          "taskType": "ComputeVmShutdownTask",
          "dailyRecurrence": {
            "time": "[parameters('autoShutdownTime')]"
          },
          "timeZoneId": "[parameters('autoShutdownTimeZone')]",
          "targetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
          "notificationSettings": {
            "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationStatus')]",
            "timeInMinutes": "30"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
          "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "ipConfigurations": [
            {
              "name": "ipconfig1",
              "properties": {
                "subnet": {
                  "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                },
                "privateipaddress": "[concat(parameters('ipaddress'))]",
                "privateIPAllocationMethod": "static"
              }
            }
          ]
        }

      },
      "outputs": [
        {
          "adminUsername": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
          }

        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.. thanks for your help :)
```

Params are below:)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "value": "westeurope"
    },
    "virtualMachineName": {
      "value": "cent-os-vm2"
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
      "value": "Standard_A0"
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "localadmin"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "value": "avset-vnet"
    },
    "networkInterfaceName": {
      "value": "cent-os-vm01652"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupName": {
      "value": "cent-os-vm01-nsg"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "value": "avsetdisks419"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
      "value": "avsetdiag112"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
      "value": "avsetdiag117"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "value": "default"
    },
    "autoShutdownStatus": {
      "value": "Enabled"
    },
    "autoShutdownTime": {
      "value": "19:00"
    },
    "autoShutdownTimeZone": {
      "value": "UTC"
    },
    "autoShutdownNotificationStatus": {
      "value": "Disabled"
    },
    "ContainerName": {
      "value": "vhd"
    },
    "offer": {
      "value": "windows"
    },
    "sku": {
      "value": "2012-R2-Datacenter"
    },
    "ipaddress": {
      "value": "10.0.1.9"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/ is a great resource for validating JSON templates.

Comment: Hi, thaks for your help, I've added the parameters :)

Comment: @NorrinRad If possible, could you show me your log?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Is ths it? `09:51:41 - [VERBOSE] Performing the operation "Creating Deployment" on target "avset".
- [ERROR] New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : Invalid property identifier character: {. 
- [ERROR] Path 'resources[0].properties.properties', line 170, position 9.
- [ERROR] avset\Linux\Linux\bin\Debug\staging\Linux\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:108 
- [ERROR] char:5
- Template deployment returned the following errors:
- Invalid property identifier character: {. Path 'resources[0].properties.properties', line 170, position 9.`

Comment: @NorrinRad Your Ipconfigurations is wrong. Please refer to this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-simple-windows/azuredeploy.json#L105)

Comment: @NorrinRad According to my test,  `"storageUri": "[concat('http://',concat(parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName')), ['blob']]"` this is wrong.  I suggest you could check this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-from-user-image/azuredeploy.json) and this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-simple-windows/azuredeploy.json#L167).

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT Thanks for your help. the template failed again, I'll start a new thread. Thanks for your help so far .. have a safe journey :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159465/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-norrin-rad).

Comment: @NorrinRad Hi, your template has many mistakes. I create a template, it works for me and similar with your need. Maybe you could check it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many mistakes in your template. The following template should work.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "location": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualMachineName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "offer": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultvalue": "windows",
      "allowedValues": [
        "windows",
        "centos",
        "RHEL"
      ]
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultvalue": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
      "allowedValues": [
        "2012-R2-Datacenter",
        "2012-R2",
        "68",
        "72",
        "73",
        "74"
      ]
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultvalue": "Standard_A0",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_A0",
        "Standard_A1",
        "standard_A2"
      ]
    },
    "adminUsername": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ipaddress": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "networkInterfaceName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "ContainerName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "autoShutdownStatus": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "autoShutdownTime": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "autoShutdownTimeZone": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "autoShutdownNotificationStatus": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "vnetId": "[resourceId('avset','Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
    "stdvhdcontainername": "[concat(parameters('Containername'))]",
    "vmosidiskname": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'-osdisk')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "apiVersion": "2016-04-30-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "diagnosticsProfile": {
            "bootDiagnostics": {
                "enabled": true,
                "storageUri": "[concat (parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName')), ['blob']]"
            }
            },
            "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
            },
            "networkProfile": {
                "networkInterfaces": [
                {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                }
            ]
            },
            "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
                "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
            },
            "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "offer": "[concat(parameters('offer'))]",
                "sku": "[concat(parameters('offer'))]",
                "version": "latest"
            }
            },
            "osDisk": {
            "vhd": {
                "name": "[variables('vmosidiskname')]",
                "uri": "[concat('http://', parameters('storageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/', variables('stdvhdcontainername'),'/', variables('vmosidiskname'), '.vhd')]"
            },
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]"
            }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat('shutdown-computevm-', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules",
            "apiVersion": "2017-04-26-preview",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
            "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownStatus')]",
            "taskType": "ComputeVmShutdownTask",
            "dailyRecurrence": {
                "time": "[parameters('autoShutdownTime')]"
            },
            "timeZoneId": "[parameters('autoShutdownTimeZone')]",
            "targetResourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
            "notificationSettings": {
                "status": "[parameters('autoShutdownNotificationStatus')]",
                "timeInMinutes": "30"
            },
                "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
                ]
            }
        },

        {
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
            ],
        "properties": {
          "ipConfigurations": [
            {
              "name": "ipconfig1",
              "properties": {
                "subnet": {
                  "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                },
                "privateipaddress": "[concat(parameters('ipaddress'))]",
                "privateIPAllocationMethod": "static"
              }
            }
          ]
        }

      }


  ],
    "outputs": {

         "adminUsername": {
           "type": "string",
           "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
          }  
      }
}
```

In line 162, it lost a `,`. Resource `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines`,`Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules`,`Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces` are in parallel. But in your template, `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines` contains others, so you get error log `with the name 'Properties' already exists`.

Note: You also need check your default value. Please note that case sensitive.

Update:
Ipconfigurations is wrong, it should like below:

```
   "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses',variables('publicIPAddressName'))]"
              },
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
```

Update 2:

The [template.json](https://gist.github.com/Walter-Shui/13ca6136191d53b6b2755378bfaa65f9) and [parameters.json](https://gist.github.com/Walter-Shui/46e6dc532bfdb2b8e9b63211d64cb3ec) works for me. Maybe you could modify your template according to this example.